# How to increase the size limit of a docker container?

Tags: docker

Context: I'm under Archlinux, and wanted to create a dockerfile as a reference for users of my program under Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial). It only has an old OpenCV version (2.4) on apt, so I need to compile OpenCV from sources.

Problem: OpenCV compilation creates more than 10G of data, which is the container size limit (visible with `df -h`), and thus crashes before finishing compilation.

Last failed attempt: I saw that there is a daemon option `--storage-opt dm.basesize=20G`. So I changed the docker.service line:

```
# from
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
# to
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G -H fd://
```

After restarting the daemon service, and pruning all my images and containers, the command `docker info` now shows "Base Device Size: 21.47GB" instead of some 10GB previously. However, every new container still have a size limit of 10G. The command `df -h` shows:

```
root@71802e5b7ba4:/# df -h
Filesystem                                                                                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-8:6-1704110-b5a7ec35a707f478a4a836ff859108092bbe32525d558d4f6661efba91313801   10G  139M  9.9G   2% /
...
```

Any idea of how I can change this?

Comment: Have you tried pruning the old volumes?

Comment: Please provide `docker info` output. I would like to see used storage driver. Did you restart docker daemon?

Comment: Yes I did prune everything and restarted the docker daemon, nothing changed. I think my issue was that somehow the storage driver (devicemapper) was not behaving correctly. It appears that devicemapper should not be used anyway.

Comment: So after trying (without success) to change from devicemapper to overlay2 I completely uninstalled docker and reinstalled it. Now the storage driver is rightfully set to overlay2, and my containers have all the space they need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it also with `devicemapper` storage driver ([old example](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/daemon_option_basedevicesize/)). You just need to remove (`docker rmi`) and build/pull used Docker images first. Change of storage driver also triggers pulls of all images from the scratch to the filesystem, so that make sense why it was working with `overlay2`.

Comment: I did remove all containers and images (`docker system prune --all`) but it did not solve anything unfortunately

Comment: Prune removes only unused images, so that is not the same.

Comment: well I had no running container, and doing `docker image ls --all` after pruning was empty. But to be sure I did try with completely new images pulled from docker hub (another base ubuntu image)